# Permission error 0x80070005 when installing and updating Microsoft Store apps as well as Windows Feature Updates

Tags: windows-update, windows-11, microsoft-store

Since about a week I cannot update any Microsoft Store apps and some Feature Updates on my PC running Windows 11.

The error code was always 0x80070005 (permission denied). Windows Update can still install Virus Definition updates, driver updates and SQL updates, but not .NET and Feature Updates.

I was still able to install the updates by downloading them directly from Microsoft Update Catalog and installing them via WUSA. Strangely, after successfully installing an update via WUSA, Windows Update in settings can still install them.

Microsoft Store can't install or update any apps anymore, with the same error message. However, if I search for an app that failed to install by running

```
Get-AppxPackage <Name>
```

The package will be listed, but with

```
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-18 [S-1-5-18]: Staged}
```

Instead of

```
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-4101337116-MyUserID-******* [MyUserName]: Installed}
```

I can still manually install the app by downloading the package from rg-adguard.net, no elevated PowerShell needed.

NOTE: I've changed my user name in Windows 11 once after installation using netplwiz

I noticed that there are some warnings in the Event Log regarding permission (they are in German so my translation may not match the message in English version):

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant user <My User Name> Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
{2593F8B9-4EAF-457C-B68A-50F6B8EA6B54}
and APPID
{15C20B67-12E7-4BB6-92BB-7AFF07997402} in application container "not available" (SID: not available). The security permission can be changed via Component Service.
```

Also, I cannot rename the folder "Administrative Tools" in Start Menu, even though I have full permission on the folder I still get permission denied error.

Another issue I noticed is that after disabling some optional features (Windows Media Player, WordPad, etc.) the start menu shortcuts must be removed manually. Also MS Store has no problem installing Win32 apps that pop up command prompt. All these phenomenons indicates that the windows setup manager has lost read/write permission, yet I don't know which files / registry entries are culprit.

Comment: 19044 suggest you are opted into to receive Insider Preview builds. Is my assumption correct? Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I didn't opted for Insider Preview... I downloaded the ISO via UUPDUMP.net installer.

Comment: In the comments you said you had installed Windows 11 also, so what build, are you actually running? If you are running Windows 11. We don’t need any of the Windows 10 information.

Comment: 22000.282, as I already mentioned.

Comment: I've edited my question to take out the old Windows 10 part and shorten it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing updates from the Microsoft Update Catalog is only counseled
for special cases. It's best to let Windows Update install them in the
correct order.

Your Windows setup is in a weird and somewhat non-functional state.
I would suggest to return everything to a known state by doing a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so take backups
appropriately.

Comment: If the author is receiving Insider Preview builds for 22H2 (it’s not yet been released) but in the Release Preview channel they will have difficulty finding an appropriate ISO. They cannot use a 21H1 ISO since that will be 19043 and you cannot in-place repair with a lower build number

Comment: @Ramhound: Your are right - Windows 10 Build 19044.1320 is 21H2. The poster must wait for the official release of 21H2, then upgrade to it. That's the danger of Insider Preview builds : the possibility if things go wrong to be required to reinstall Windows from scratch.

Comment: [Updating from an expiring Insider Preview build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/build-expiration): "To move off the Insider Preview build expiring on your device, you can either get preview builds in the Dev Channel, reinstall Windows using a Windows Insider ISO to move to the Beta channel, or start fresh with a clean installation of Windows 10".

Comment: I didn't join the Insider Program and installed unknowingly a Preview Build via UUPDump.ml. I've done a clean install of Windows 11 22000.282, but strangely the error appears again albeit not immediately (see the edit to my question).

Comment: Windows 11 is as experimental as 21H2. I suggest going back to 21H1.

Comment: @user167420 - So now your on Windows 11? Well you definitely cannot perform a repair install of Windows 10 if your running Windows 11.