# In Windows 11, what's the registry key that controls whether "details" side panel in Explorer is shown?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-11, regedit

I frequently do in-place upgrade to Windows 11 since [Windows Update doesn't work on my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1685913/permission-error-0x80070005-when-installing-and-updating-microsoft-store-apps-as). After each upgrade, the "detail" tile on the right side of explorer will be hidden and I have to manually switch it on.

I use a PowerShell script to automatically do some stuff I frequently have to do after OOBE or in-place upgrade, including importing registry keys. So I want to include "showing details tile" into my script, though I don't know where I should look at. Anyone knows where under HKCR:\ or HKLM:\ is the shown/hidden status of details tile stored?

Comment: Windows 11 Update works flawlessly on my two Production Windows 11 machines.  Maybe just use vanilla Windows instead of running updates with Powershell.

Comment: Read my previous question in the link. The Windows Update error persists no matter what version of Windows I use and can't be fixed even with fresh installation. I've long given up fixing the issue as nobody can recreate my problem for almost one year long.

Comment: I am not sure why your install gets messed up. I have been on Windows 11 since July 2021 and there is no such problem as you described. Try contacting Microsoft Support.

Comment: M$ Support is useless for non-business private users. They would just give some general replies about resetting computer or so. I don't even believe they even read my message.

Comment: I have gotten help from them in past (ordinary user) so I cannot add anything else

Comment: If you run Process Monitor with an `operation` filter for `RegSetValue` and toggle the option in the UI you can see the `DetailsContainer` value is set under this key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\DetailsContainer`. My guess you can import/set this key.